# shortest path optimization for multiple edge attributes

Tags: networks

Say I have a network. The edges each have two attributes: age and height. How might I run a shortest path algorithm that optimizes on both age and height? And could I weight it so that it optimizes 0.7 on age and 0.3 on height, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_{ij}$ and $H_{ij}$ denote the age and height attributes of an edge from node $i$ to node $j$. Suppose we want to weight age and height by some fractions $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. Then, we can construct the combined edge lengths $D$, where the length of an edge from node $i$ to node $j$ is $D_{ij} = \alpha A_{ij} + \beta H_{ij}$. This means the length of any given path when measured using the combined edge lengths is $\alpha$ times the path length when measured using age, plus $\beta$ times the path length when measured using height.

Using the combined edge lengths $D$, the shortest path between any two nodes (and its length) can be computed as usual. For example, using [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: it doesn't matter that they are different units? yrs and meters

Comment: Yes, this will affect the solution. But, how to deal with it is problem dependent. For example, you'd have to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ appropriately, and/or normalize age/height so that they have common units (e.g. standard deviations) or are unit-less (e.g. fraction of the max).